# How to assign a custom id to socket, that works on socket.id not socket.conn.id

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

When I try to assign a custom `socket.id`

```js
io.engine.generateId = (req) => {
    return 13543; 
}
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log(socket.id) // it logs jkpK0bLe8_O4uVG5AAAA
    console.log(socket.conn.id) // it logs 13543
})
```

The problem is that `generateId` changes the id of `socket.conn.id` not `socket.id` itself.

So I would like for `socket.id` to be equal to 13543, not `socket.conn.id`.